# SharingCapability SharePoint Online Site Collection c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to set the SharingCapability property after provisioning my site collection. I used the documentation of PnP, as you can find here ([External Sharing APIs for SharePoint and OneDrive for Business (Core.ExternalSharing)](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ExternalSharing))

When I set the property to 'ExternalUserAndGuestSharing', nothing happens. The site collection is still disabled to share with external.

Here is my code:

```
        public static void SetSharingCapability(string fullWebUrl, ClientContext context)
    {
        Tenant tenant = new Tenant(context);
        SiteProperties siteProp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(fullWebUrl, true);
        context.Load(siteProp);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        siteProp.SharingCapability = SharingCapabilities.ExternalUserAndGuestSharing;
        siteProp.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Do you habe any suggestions for solving the 'problem'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the moment once settings (`SharingCapability`) are applied, the operation itself is not yet completed and that the reason why updated settings are not yet reflected:

```
siteProp.SharingCapability = SharingCapabilities.ExternalUserAndGuestSharing;
siteProp.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();  //<- even though the query is submitted to the server there is no guarantee at this moment the update operation is completed
```

To *ensure* the update operation is completed you could consider the following solution:

```
public static void SetSharingCapability(string fullWebUrl, ClientContext context)
{
        Tenant tenant = new Tenant(context);
        SiteProperties siteProp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(fullWebUrl, true);

        siteProp.SharingCapability = SharingCapabilities.Disabled;
        siteProp.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        siteProp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(fullWebUrl, true);
        context.Load(siteProp, p => p.Status);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        while (siteProp.Status == "Updating")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            siteProp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(fullWebUrl, true);
            context.Load(siteProp);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Okay, that is an interesting point. Do you know the reason why there is no guarantee the update is completed on `context.ExecuteQuery();`? But thanks to your support and the solution!

Comment: It seems some "long  running" operations (like this one) against tenant site collection are queue based, meaning  the invocation of method context.ExecuteQuery(); is intended to put this operation into a queue